# Please explain "they'll initiate out of a down screen"

Tags: basketball, terminology

It is about basketball play and I don't understand what 'out of a down screen' is.
Could anybody explain it for me please?

> >
>   they gonna start off with a pick-and-roll, and then they gonna start playing from there, or **they'll initiate out of a down screen.**

Answer (score 1):

**Down Screens (also know as Pin Downs)** according to [HoopTactics](https://hooptactics.net/premium/player/offskilldevelopment/screensoffball.php):

> Down Screens are the most commonly used Off-Ball screens. They are primarily used to free up good shooters. Simple, but when well executed, they are a very effective means for getting the ball to good shooters for open shots.

[image]

I found a interesting [youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZhVpcFSFPmU). Here you can see some work on setting a Down Screen.

Best Regards.